# make grid view auto scrollable

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid

I have a grid. I have a button down that if i click on that button it will add an empty row to that grid in which i will edit and save. I need to display a scroll bar so that when i click on that button it will add empty row in the end of grid with scroll bar at the end

```
<div id="Div" runat="server" class="divFieldRow">           
         <div>
         <center>  
         <div  style="overflow: auto; height: 150px">
                 <asp:GridView ID="gvEventMechanic" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5"
                            GridLines="None" AllowSorting="true" BorderWidth="1"
                            BorderColor="Brown" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Cyan" HeaderStyle-BackColor="ActiveCaption"
                            FooterStyle-BackColor="DimGray" EnableViewState="true" >                         
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>                    
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Disable
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>                           
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbDelete_OnCheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField >                     
                       <HeaderTemplate>Event</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" Visible='<%# ! IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description")%>' MaxLength="255">
                            </asp:TextBox>                                                        
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                 </Columns>                
            </asp:GridView>     
        </div> 
     </center>
  </div>
```

Comment: its ok if we can achieve this with pagination and not necessarily with scroll bar. Please hel me in getting the solution

Comment: The only way I know to move the scroll is with anchors.  So try including an anchor on the bottom or just below the grid, then Response.Redirect back to the page + the anchor for the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Using a div that wraps the grid with fixed height and overflow should do the trick in case the table exceeds the fixed height. With paging involved you may switch to the last available page in the grid and rebind it, if that is what you want to achieve.